# Correct way to handle exceptions > Click button > Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Correct way to handle exceptions > Click button > Webdriver?

My code:

```
public void clickSearchButton() throws Exception{
    try{
        app.safeClickOnElement(SEARCH_BUTTON);
    }catch (Exception e){
        throw new Exception("unable to click button" + e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally like to let errors bubble up. In this case, if you try to interact with an element, such as clicking a link, a selenium exception will be thrown if there's a problem with the interaction. For example, it could throw a stale element exception or an element not found exception, depending on what the problem is. In my opinion, if you add this try catch block, you won't actually know what the real issue is.

I recommend keeping the default exception mapping as much as possible.